# GenericPool to reuse sprites needed every second

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have created this Pool that has 5 static variables.

```
public class FruitPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {
// ===========================================================
// Constants          
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================          
// Fields         
// =========================================================== 
private  ITextureRegion texture1;
private  ITextureRegion texture2;
private ITextureRegion texture3;
private  ITextureRegion texture4;
private  ITextureRegion texture5;

private Scene mScene;
private Context mContext;
private Camera mCamera;
private LinkedList<Sprite>pool1;

private static Sprite fruitOne;
private static Sprite fruitTwo;
private static Sprite fruitThree;
private static Sprite fruitFour;
private static Sprite fruitFive;
private  Sprite fruit;
// ===========================================================          
// Constructors          
// =========================================================== 
public FruitPool(final ITextureRegion watermelonRegion,
        ITextureRegion cherryRegion,ITextureRegion mBallTextureRegion, ITextureRegion grapeTextureRegion, ITextureRegion strawberryTextureRegion,Scene mScene2, Camera camera, LinkedList<Sprite>items) {

    this.texture1 = watermelonRegion;
    this.texture2 =cherryRegion;
    this.texture3 = mBallTextureRegion;
    this.texture4 = grapeTextureRegion;
    this.texture5 = strawberryTextureRegion;
    this.mScene = mScene2;
    this.pool1 = items;

    this.mCamera = camera;

}
// ===========================================================          
// Getter & Setter          
// =========================================================== 

// ===========================================================          
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces          
// ===========================================================  
@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {


     Random randFruit = new Random();

     int textureNumber = randFruit.nextInt(5)+1;

     switch(textureNumber){
     case 1:
         if (fruitOne == null) {
              fruitOne = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture1);
              Log.e("FruitPool", "Item rremade");
            } else {
              fruit = fruitOne;
              Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
            }
          break;
     case 2:
         if(fruitTwo == null){
          fruitTwo = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture2);
         }else{
             fruit = fruitTwo;
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
         }

         break;
     case 3:
         if(fruitThree == null){
              fruitThree = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture3);
         }else{
             fruit = fruitThree;
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
         }

         break;
     case 4:
         if(fruitFour == null){
             fruitFour = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture4);
         }else{
             fruit = fruitThree;
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");

         }

         break;
     case 5:
         if(fruitFive == null){
              fruitFive = new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture5);
         }else{
             fruit = fruitFive;
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
         }

         break;

     }


    return fruit;

}
@Override
protected void onHandleObtainItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.reset();
}
@Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    pItem.setVisible(false);
    pItem.setIgnoreUpdate(true);

}



// ===========================================================          
// Methods          
// ===========================================================  

// ===========================================================          
// Inner and Anonymous Classes          
// ===========================================================  
}
```

As you see in my onAllocate method i check to see if the item exist's if it does i return it in the method.

So in my main activity i use

```
          face =  fruitsPool.onAllocatePoolItem();
```

This works initially but the problem is i attach the face to the scene about every second.And i get the error that the sprite has already been attached to the scene. At first the only way i found to do this was to create a new Sprite each second, and detach it when im finished with it, but this uses wayy to much memory and causes lag, na freezes.

Does anyone have any pointers for what i  need to do, or suggestions for me code?

Comment: Attach to the scene, when i Sprite = onAllocateItem() i then attach whatever sprite is passed to the scene.

Comment: Don't label your `ITextureRegion`s as `texture1` - `5`.  They're either _specific_ regions (as your constructor seems to indicate), and should be labelled as such, or you have (what amounts to) a `List` (or possibly `Map`) of elements, and should use the collection.  Generally, any time variables are created with indexed names, it's a code smell.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the advise, so would this help in what i am trying to do?

Comment: @Snicolas In angine, i attach it meaning i use it in my scene.. Scene.attach(Sprite);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *never* call `onAllocatePoolItem`. This method is called internally in the `GenericPool<T>` class when the pool is empty and an item is requested.

The *only* methods you should be calling from outside of your `FruitPool` class are:

1. `obtainPoolItem` to get a pool item; *Not* `onAllocatePoolItem`.
2. `recyclePoolItem` to recycle an item. Remember to call it when you are done with the item.
3. `batchAllocatePoolItems`, but you don't need it in your case. It could be used when you want to create the pool items at a certain point; But initiating `Sprite`'s is not a heavy process, so you don't need.

You shouldn't call any other methods.

Again, you are breaking the purpose of the object pool! `onAllocatePoolItem` should  **always**  return a *brand new* object! Not an existing one! That's the reason you get the

> Entity already has a parent

error.

By the way, when I first built this class for you, I attached the sprite to the scene when it's created. Why aren't you doing it now?

I have edited it, and added some comments.

```
public class FruitPool extends GenericPool<Sprite> {
// ===========================================================
// Constants          
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================          
// Fields         
// =========================================================== 
private ITextureRegion[] mTextureRegions = new ITextureRegion[5];
private Scene mScene;
private int mCount;
// ===========================================================          
// Constructors          
// =========================================================== 
public FruitPool(final ITextureRegion watermelonRegion, ITextureRegion cherryRegion,ITextureRegion mBallTextureRegion, ITextureRegion grapeTextureRegion, ITextureRegion strawberryTextureRegion,Scene attachedScene) {
    this.mTextureRegions[0] = watermelonRegion;
    this.mTextureRegions[1] =cherryRegion;
    this.mTextureRegions[2]= mBallTextureRegion;
    this.mTextureRegions[3]= grapeTextureRegion;
    this.mTextureRegions[4] = strawberryTextureRegion;
    this.mScene = attachedScene;
}
// ===========================================================          
// Getter & Setter          
// =========================================================== 

// ===========================================================          
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces          
// ===========================================================  
@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {
    //This method is called internally by GenericPool<T> class.
    //It is called when the pool is out of items, so a new one should be allocated.
    //Remember - you MUST create a new item here! Don't return a reference to an existing one.
    int fruitPos = MathUtils.random(0, 4);
    final Sprite fruit = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mTextureRegions[fruitPos]);
    this.mScene.attachChild(fruit);
    return fruit;
}
@Override
protected void onHandleObtainItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    //Before we return the sprite to the caller, we reset it's fields.
    //This method is called internaly by GenericPool<T> class.
    pItem.reset();
}
@Override
protected void onHandleRecycleItem(final Sprite pItem) {
    //When an item is recycled, this method is called. We make it invisible and set it to ignores updates.
    //We DONT detach it from the scene, just make it ignore updates.
    //Again, this method is called internally by GenericPool<T>class.
    pItem.setVisible(false);
    pItem.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
}
// ===========================================================          
// Methods          
// ===========================================================  

// ===========================================================          
// Inner and Anonymous Classes          
// ===========================================================  
}
```

Remember - you *don't* attach/detach a sprite from the pool! It is attached once when it's created.

Comment: Jong to the rescue again! Thanks! Ive figured out this last night, and got it working correctly!

Comment: Thanks -- your example pointed out attaching the child in the onAllocatedPoolItem method which seems to be the way to avoid performance problems associated with attaching and detaching the object to the scene manually each time.

Comment: Well, attaching/detaching shouldn't create any overhead (These are just simple `ArrayList.add` and `ArrayList.remove` methods) but it could create other issues, so I think this way is better.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if this helps. See if this helps. Why do you need a LinkedList? You can use arrays, right?

```
private final Fruit fruits[] = new Fruits[4];
//Initialize this in the constructor...
for(int i =0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    fruits[i] = new Fruits();
}

@Override
protected Sprite onAllocatePoolItem() {


     Random randFruit = new Random();

     int textureNumber = randFruit.nextInt(5)+1;

     switch(textureNumber){
     case 1:
         if (fruitOne == null) {
              fruitOne = fruits[textureNumber];
              //new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture1);
              //use setters to set the values here..
              Log.e("FruitPool", "Item rremade");
            } else {
              fruit = fruits[textureNumber];
              Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
            }
          break;
     case 2:
         if(fruitTwo == null){
              fruitTwo = fruits[textureNumber];
          //new Sprite(0, 0, this.texture1);
          //use setters to set the values here..
              Log.e("FruitPool", "Item rremade");
         }else{
             fruit = fruits[textureNumber];
             Log.e("FruitPool", "Item exist in pool..Used");
         }
....
```

Comment: Hmmm Interesting so how would this intern fix my issue?